# java Lab Remove all non-alpha characters

Tags: java

> Write a program that removes all non alpha characters from the given
> input.
>
> Ex: If the input is:
> -Hello, 1 world$!
>
> the output is: Helloworld

My issue is that I can only return the first word "Hello". This section is on loops, so I'm trying to use a loop.

```java
import java.util.Scanner;

public class LabProgram {
   public static void main(String[] args) {
      Scanner scnr = new Scanner(System.in);
      String uInput = scnr.next();
      String result = "";
      
      for (int i = 0; i < uInput.length(); i++) {
         char c = uInput.charAt(i);
         if (Character.isLetter(c)) {
            result += c;
         }
      }
      System.out.println(result);
            
   }
}
```

Comment: can you please explain what do you want as a result ? you program is throwing IndexOutOfBound exception.

Comment: `scnr.next()` → `scnr.nextLine()` ?

Comment: @NiteshSharma no it doesn't?

Comment: that was it...why did I not think of that. Thank you so much

Comment: Please don't edit your question to add things like "resolved" to the title, and changing the body of the question to fix the problem. If you managed to solve your problem, that's great, but you mark a question as solved by accepting an answer(if it answered your question), if there is no current answer (or none that actually identify the problem), then post your own answer describing the solution in sufficient detail and accept it after the timeout.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel My apologies, first time user of this site. will keep in mind for the future.

Answer (score 1):

@teapot418 was correct scnr.next() → scnr.nextLine() fixed the issue.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class LabProgram {
   public static void main(String[] args) {
      Scanner scnr = new Scanner(System.in);
      String uInput = scnr.nextLine();
      String result = "";
      
      for (int i = 0; i < uInput.length(); i++) {
         char c = uInput.charAt(i);
         if (Character.isLetter(c)) {
            result += c;
         }
      }
      System.out.println(result);          
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all when you use `scan.next()` you get an input up to the next space character. You should use `scan.nextLine()` instead.

Second, do not use string concatenation in loop. Do use `StringBuilder` instead.

Ohter you code is fine.

```java
public static void main(String... args) {
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println(removeNotLetters(scan.nextLine()));
}

public static String removeNotLetters(String str) {
    StringBuilder buf = new StringBuilder(str.length());

    for (int i = 0; i < str.length(); i++) {
        char ch = str.charAt(i);

        if (Character.isLetter(ch))
            buf.append(ch);
    }

    return buf.toString();
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately due to the restrictions of the lab, a loop is needed for completion. String builder maybe to advanced for my intro course?

Answer (score 0):

If you're learning loops, then you'll eventually also see the [Enhanced For Loop](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/for.html):

```
for (char c : uInput.toCharArray()) {
   if (Character.isLetter(c)) {
      result += c;
   }
}
```